# Check box validation-to validate at least one is selected

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Need help in validating whether at least one check box is checked or not using java script.

**Work flow:**

1.The user selects the check box values

2.After selecting the values ,the user hits save button

If no check box values are selected then an alert should be raised to select at least one check box value

This is the code

**products.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="web.Products"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Validate()

    {
        var x[]=document.forms["sform"]["prod"].value;
        for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            if(x[i].type=='checkbox'&&x[i].checked==false)
                {
                    alert("Please select the products available and click save");
                    return false;
                }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

    <body>
     <form name="sform" method="post" action="Save_Products" onsubmit="javascript:return Validate();"> 
<b>          
            Brand Name:<font color="green">
            <% String brand_name=(String)session.getAttribute("brand_name");
       out.print(brand_name);%> 
        <c:set var="brand_name" value="brand_name" scope="session"  />
       </font></b>         
            <table>            
                <tr>                
                    <th> Products</th> 
                    <th> Description </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
               <td> <b><%
      List<Products> pdts = (List<Products>) request.getAttribute("list");
      if(pdts!=null){
        for(Products prod: pdts){
           out.println("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"prod\" value=\""  + prod.getProductname() + "\">"  + prod.getProductname()+"<br>");
            } %> </b></td>   

            <td><%for(Products prod: pdts){
            out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\" style=\"width:50px; height:22px\"/><br/>"); 
        } 

      }  
            %> </td>  

        </tr>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <tr><td align="center">  <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/> </td></tr> 
            </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why are you returning false?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but don't tag java in javascript questions, they have nothing to do with one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript Validate() function looks like it has a logical error.

Currently, as soon as you find one checkbox that is false, you return false and alert the user. To get the desired result, you should only return false once you've checked that all of the checkboxes are false (and if even one checkbox is true, then return true).

The below function is probably close to what you are looking for.

```
function Validate() {
    var x[]=document.forms["sform"]["prod"].value;
    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(x[i].type=='checkbox'&&x[i].checked==true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    alert("Please select the products available and click save");
    return false;
}
```

**Edit:
Updated the code. There is a syntax error when declaring the x array (remove "[]") and we need to initialize x to the entire array, so remove ".value" from the end.**

```
function Validate() {
var x=document.forms["sform"]["prod"];
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    if(x[i].type=='checkbox'&&x[i].checked==true) {
        return true;
    }
}
alert("Please select the products available and click save");
return false;
```

}

Comment: It is not working.Is there any other logic which can be used to validate the check box entries?

Comment: I fixed a couple of errors in the declaration and initialization of x in the function. Hopefully it will work now.